Localisation $S^{-1}R$ of Dedekind domain by multiplicative set is again a Dedekind domain
Let $R$ be a Dedekind domain, with fraction field $K$ and let $S \subset R$ be a multiplicatively closed subset. Show that the localisation of $R$ by $S$  denoted $S^{-1}R$ is again a Dedekind domain.
Hint: You can freely use that there is a correspondence between ideals in $R$ and the localisation $S^{-1}R$, where an ideal $I \subset R$ is sent to the (so-called extended) ideal $\rho(I)S^{-1}R$ for the ring homomorphism $\rho: R \to S^{-1}R$ given by $r \mapsto \frac{r}{1}$, and every ideal in $S^{-1}R$ is equal to an extended ideal (note that there may be different ideals in $R$ which correspond to the same extended ideal in $S^{-1}R$).
My try:
I have already proven that it is integrally closed, but I have doubts about the other two properties:
(1) To prove that $S^{-1}R$ is Noetherian, take an ascending chain of ideals in $S^{-1}R$ :
$J_1 \subseteq... \subseteq J_n \subseteq.... $ Since by the hint every ideal there is an extended ideal, there exist ideals $I_1,...I_n,...$ in R such that $J_1=\rho(I_1)S^{-1}R , ...,J_n=\rho(I_n)S^{-1}R...$
so we have:
$ \rho(I_1)S^{-1}R \subseteq... \subseteq \rho(I_n)S^{-1}R \subseteq.... $ which must stabilize because $R$ is noetherian. How can I conclude $I_1 \subseteq... \subseteq I_n \subseteq.... $ ?
The problem is that since $\rho$ is not injective.
Supposing that I can prove that, then $\rho(I_1)\subseteq... \subseteq \rho(I_n) \subseteq$ would also stabilize and I would have the proof. Or perhaps I don't even need this, and I can say that they stabilize?
(2) To prove that every non-zero prime ideal is maximal, take a prime ideal $P$ in $S^{-1}R$. Supposed an  ideal $J$ is such that $P\subseteq J\subseteq S^{-1}R$. By the correspondence we have $I_P$ and $I_J$ ideals in R sucha that $J=\rho(I_J)S^{-1}R$ and $P=\rho(I_P)S^{-1}R$, so
$\rho(I_P)S^{-1}R \subseteq \rho(I_J)S^{-1}R$ , How can I argue that $I_P \subseteq I_J$ ? with $I_P$ presumedly a prime ideals in $R$. How do I prove that?
If I had that it is prime,then it is maximal because $R$ is Dedekind then $I_J=I_P$ or $I_J=R$ would imply
$J=\rho(I_J)S^{-1}R=\rho(I_P)S^{-1}R=I$ or $J=\rho(I_J)S^{-1}R=\rho(R)S^{-1}R=S^{-1}R$ ie. that J is maximal
My questions are:

In (1) How can I conclude that   $I_1 \subseteq... \subseteq I_n \subseteq.... $ ?
In (2) how can I argue that $I_P \subseteq I_J $ and that $I_P$ is also a prime ideal ?
Is there a unique maximal ideal in R? Inclusion is a partial order so in principal there could be many elements that are maximal, but I really need to know that maximal elements are.

I know  there might other ways to prove it (like using in (1) that Noetherian is equivalent to every ideal being finitely generated) ,but I am interested in seeing how these arguments can be completed instead of alternative proofs.

To prove that $S^{-1}R$ is Noetherian, take an ideal $I \subset S^{-1}R$; since it is an extended ideal, $I = \rho(J)S^{-1}R$ for some ideal $J \subset R$. But $R$ Noetherian implies that $J$ is finitely generated, say, $J = (a_1, a_2 \ldots, a_n)$.  But this implies $I = (a_1/1, a_2/1, \ldots, a_n/1)$ and is thus also finitely generated.
I am not sure though how to prove (or disprove) that every non-zero prime ideal in $S^{-1}R$ is maximal. I have not been able to find a counter-example to disprove it.
Edit: One can prove the latter statement as follows: Let $I$ be a non-zero prime ideal in $S^{-1}R$; therefore $I \cap R = \cal{P}$ is a non-zero prime ideal in $R$ and hence maximal. Suppose, if possible, that $I$ is not maximal in $S^{-1}R$; then there exists a maximal ideal $J \subset S^{-1}R$ such that $I \subset J$. It follows that
$J \cap R$ is a non-zero prime ideal in $R$ that contains $\cal{P}$ and hence $J \cap R = I\cap R = \cal{P}$ (since $\cal{P}$ is maximal).
But this implies that $J = I$ and hence $I$ is maximal in $S^{-1}R$.

Actually the finitely generated argument I knew already about, that 's what I said I was interested in completing the arguments that I initiated, ie, using  an ascending chain of indeals in (1), not the finitely generated argument.

Also notice that $\rho(J)$ does not give an ideal yet, only the generators I presume, the ideal is $\rho(J)S^{-1}R$

You cannot disprove that every non-zero prime ideal in $S^{-1}R$ is maximal because it is true, the problem is how to prove it.

I have corrected one error that you have pointed out above.
